# Rudin proof verification Excercise 1.6c

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, exponentiation

> $\bf Exercise\, 1.6$
>
> Fix $b>1.$
>
> If $x$ is real, define $B(x)$ to be the set of all numbers $b^t$, where $t$ is rational and $t\leq x$. Prove that
>
> $$b^r =\sup B(r)$$ where $r$ is rational. Hence it makes sense to define
> $$b^x =\sup B(x)$$ where $x$ is real.

## Problem

The method to such proofs is generally

1. Show that a number is the upper-bound.
2. Show that number is the least upper-bound.

Much of the proofs I have seen tackle the following in this manner.

1. $b^r = b^tb^{r-t}\geq b^t$
2. Recall $b^r \in B(r) $ hence $b^r = \max B(r) = \sup B(r) $

But this proof (the 2. part) cannot be extrapolated to $x$ which is not necessarily rational since for any irrational $x$ $b^x \notin B(x)$ hence $b^x \neq \max B(x)$

Are my concerns correct? If yes, can somebody provide an alternative route for proving for $r$?

(It would be very much helpful if somebody can prove it using just the established axioms till the first chapter in Baby Rudin.)

Comment: This is why it is so awkward to define exponentiation like this; it is so much better to start with the logarithm. In any case, I fail to see what the problem is: you don't have to prove anything for $x$: "it makes sense to **define** $b^x=\sup B(x)$.

Comment: I am aware I dont have to prove anything for $x$. But the problem is hinting that the proof that I am providing for rationals should also be applicable for reals. And for reals, the proof fails (2 doesn't hold).

Comment: I don't follow. I don't know who's hinting that the proof for the rationals is applicable for the reals. And, as you yourself said, in the case of $x$ it is a definition, so there is nothing to prove. Once you have exponentiation defined for all real powers, you make take $C(x)=\{b^y:\ y\leq x\}$, and in that case the proof applies and $b^x=\max C(x)$.

Comment: Defining the exponentiation for real powers is in the next part of this question.

Comment: $b^x$ for $x $ irrational is not defined. But $\supB(x) $ exist whether $x $ is rational or not. We need to prove that if $r$ is rational then $\sup B (r)=b^r $. That's all. If $x $ is irrational, you know that $\sup B(x)$ exist but you have (as of now) no way to express it except as $\sup B (x)$.  You can use the notation $b^x$ to mean $\sup B (x) $ except that would be confusing because if $r $ is rational we wouldn't know if that meant $b $ to the $r $ power or if it meant $\sup B(r)$. But that's not an issue because $b $ to the $r $ power *is* $\sup B(r)$. So we *can* use that notation.

Comment: It would be very unfair of Rudin to say "let us use the word Rangnuffin to mean the king of the dwarves.  Now an an exercise, prove that the king of the dwarves is Rangnuffin".  That'd hardly be fair would it?

Comment: "But the problem is hinting that the proof that I am providing for rationals should also be applicable for reals."  Claim:  $b^x = \sup B(x)$.  Proof:  Case 1:  $x \in \mathbb Q$.  Then we do the proof Jose Carlos Santos did.  Case 2: $x \not \in \mathbb Q$.  Then $b^x = \sup B(x)$ because that is the definition of $b^x$ when $x$ is not rational.  End of Proof.  Done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $b>1$, the function $t\mapsto b^t$ is increasing. So$$b^r=\sup_{t\leqslant r}b^t=B(r).$$

Comment: So basically for any $x \in R$ and $x>t$ $b^t<b^x = \sup B(x)$?

Comment: @mathnoob123 No. What I wrote was for $t\in\mathbb Q$. What you wrote is valid only after you've proved that, in $\mathbb R$, the function $t\mapsto b^t$ is strictly increasing. You haven't proved it yet, right?!

Comment: Well, I already proved for $r$ (The 1. in the question). I have trouble proving for $x$.

Comment: @mathnoob123 I'm confused. Do you agree or not that I solved exercise 1.6?

Comment: Yes, you proved exercise 1.6. But can your proof be extrapolated to reals? If yes, please explain how? If not, can you extend your proof to include reals?

Comment: @mathnoob123 If $x,y\in\mathbb R$ with $x<y$, let $p,q\in\mathbb Q$ such that $x<p<q<y$. Then $b^x\leqslant b^p<b^q\leqslant b^y$. Therefore, $b^x<b^y$. Since the function $x\mapsto b^x$ is strictly increasing, my previous argument applies.

Comment: So is that enough to prove that $b^x$ is increasing in $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: @mathnoob123 Well... That's what I proved, right?!

Comment: You are missing the point that $b^x$ where $x $ is not rational hasn't been defined. So asking if you can extend the to reals makes no more sense then asking if you can extend the result to goldfish. What does $b^{freddie\ the\ fish} $ mean? But if we defined $b^x=\supB (x)$ if $x$ is not rational. Then we know it is true because we SAID it was true. Just like if we defined $b^x=27$ if $x $ is irrational we would know $\pi^{\sqrt 2}=27$ because we SAID it was. But that's a stupid definition so we don't use it. Instead we use the definition $b^x:=\sup B (x) $.

Comment: If $x\not \in \mathbb Q $ then $b^x =\sup B (x) $ because that is the DEFINITION of $b^x $.  There is nothing to prove because that was the definition of $b^x $.   Can you prove that given a circle that the ratio of the circumference to diameter is $\pi $?  No, you can not.  You can prove it is constant but you can prove the constant is $\pi $ because $\pi $ DEFINED to be the constant.  You can't prove $b^x=\sup B (x) $ because that is the DEFINITION of $b^x $.

Answer (score 4):

You are missing the point of the exercise.

The exercise is to *extend* the definition of $b^n; n \in \mathbb N$ to $b^x; x \in \mathbb R$.

At this point $b^n$ is defined to mean "$b$ multiplied by itself $n$ times".  This fine but it's not a very useful definition.  What if $x \not \in \mathbb N$.  What does $b^x$ mean then?

So we *extend* the definition.  Well we defined $b^{\frac 1n}$ to mean the positive number $c$ so that $c^n = b$.  This had *NOTHING* whatsoever to do with $b^n$ equaling $b*b*b... *b$ and the fact that they both looked like $b^{something}$ was entirely coincidental.

So we have $b^n = b*b*...*b$ by definition. And $b^x$ is utterly undefined.  We'll define $b^{\frac nm}$ as $c^n$ where $c^m = b$.  Now, wait, you ought to be saying.  That's an *ENTIRELY* different definition and has *nothing* to do with the old definition $b^n = b*b*b....*b$.

But that's okay, because we are *extending* a definition.  We just have to prove that with the *new* definition of $b^{\frac nm} = c^n; c^m =b$ that *IF* $\frac nm = k \in \mathbb N$ then $b^{\frac nm} = c^n$ will *also* be so that $b^{\frac nm} = b*b*b*...*b$ $k$ times.

If so, the *new* definition does 1) agrees with the old one and 2) allows for the term $b^x$ to be defined for more cases of $x$.

It does.

Okay.  So $b^r; r\in \mathbb Q$ is defined.  But $b^x; x \not \in \mathbb Q$ is *NOT* defined.

We need to *extend* the definition.

So we do that by DEFINING $b^x := \sup \{b^r| r\in \mathbb Q; r \le x\}$.

That will be our *new* definition and it will be a good one if it does the two things:

1) agrees with the old one and 2) allows for the term $b^x$ to be defined for more cases of $x$.

Well, it certainly does number 2) but does it do number 1)?  That's what we have to prove.

If $r \in \mathbb Q$ does $b^r = \sup B(r)$.  If so then the new definition agrees with the old one.

So you prove it for $r\in \mathbb Q$.

!!!!YOU DO ***NOT*** HAVE TO PROVE $b^x = \sup B(x)$ if $x \not \in \mathbb Q$.  You CAN'T prove it even if you wanted to.... because that is the DEFINITION of $b^x; x \not \in \mathbb Q$.

Comment: This is beautifully said. This dialogue should virtually be restated verbatim in most Real Analysis classes.

Comment: This was a superb answer, thanks! As an aside, the statement that "We'll define $b^{\frac nm}$ as $c^n$ where $c^m=b$" seems to invert the order of integer exponentiation and n-th rooting implied by Rudin in the definition. I suppose it is to be proved that the order of these operations does not matter?

Comment: Oh, it probably does matter. I forget the order they were defined. But it can be proven (and probably needs to be proven) that the order doesn't matter.  I also omitted the we have to prove that if $n,m,u,w\in \mathbb N$ so that $\frac nm = \frac uw$ that we must prove $(b^{\frac 1m})^n = (b^{\frac 1w})^u$ (is that the right order?) (That was part b) of the excercise).